# Query based on multi-select picklist

Tags: apex, multi-select

I have a method that searches for records based on a picklist value on the user record. We set the picklsit value and the query does a simple search based on the name.

Example:

```
user = [
        SELECT Department, BudgetToolRole__c, User_BU__c, User_Region__c, User_Sector__c 
        FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    ];

Practice__c p = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Practice__c WHERE Name = :user.User_BU__c];
```

Now, I have the requirement that the picklist field should really be a multi-select picklist and that there should be multiple practice records returned. So based on the above I want to get the values of the multi-select and then run the query on them.

Example:

```
String strPA = [SELECT Budget_Cross_Practice__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1][0].Budget_Cross_Practice__c;

List<Practice__c> pas = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Practice__c WHERE Name = :strPA];
```

This complies in anonymous apex but no results are returned. The string returns a value in debug statement value1;values2;value3

I tried changing the = to IN but I get no luck.

How can I perform a query based on values in a multi-select?

Comment: The `Name` field cannot possibly be a multi-select picklist?

Comment: The custom field "Budget_Cross_practice__c" matches to the name of the Practice__c object. We have many business units called practices that get their own custom record to relate everywhere. users can be assigned a practice hence the singular picklist but then in some cases they can be assigned to multiple hence the need to have the multi-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LIKE` operator:

```
String strPA = [SELECT Budget_Cross_Practice__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1][0].Budget_Cross_Practice__c;
String likeStrPA = '%' + strPA + '%';
List<Practice__c> pas = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Practice__c WHERE Name LIKE :likeStrPA];
```

However, this will run into issues if any option is contained in another.  A more robust solution is to split your multi-select field into a `List<String>`:

```
String strPA = [SELECT Budget_Cross_Practice__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1][0].Budget_Cross_Practice__c;
List<String> strPASplit = strPA.split(';');
List<Practice__c> pas = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Practice__c WHERE Name IN :strPASplit];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `IN` clause to find the matching from multi-select picklist. `IN` clause always take `Iterable` element. So, either store `strPA` as List or Set and use that in SOQL.

```
String strPA = [SELECT Budget_Cross_Practice__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1][0].Budget_Cross_Practice__c;

List<String> strList = strPA.split(';');

List<Practice__c> pas = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Practice__c WHERE Name IN:strList];
```

Comment: If I change to IN I get the error: IN operator must be used with an iterable expression. Thoughts?

Comment: updated my answer, it should run